# Convert Multiple Groovy Jar files to a single DLL by IKVMC

Tags: dll, groovy, ikvm

I am about to convert groovy jar files into one .dll through using IKVMC and here the command I have used:

```
Ikvmc –out:groovy.dll –target:library –recurse:"C:\Mehad\Source\Groovy-2.2.2\lib\*.jar"
```

It generates the .dll but there is some doubt! Due to the fact that there are several jar files in groovy java package, there is a big doubt if IKVMS is able to take into account the dependencies.

Does anyone know whether IKVMC is able to configure all the dependencies? I mean, Is it enough to just run the mentioned command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer!

The groovy package bundle comes with a groovy-all.x.jar. Which is the single ot-of-the-box jar file. It can be found in the "embded" folder of the package.